# SDP parser (usign bison?)

Tags: bison, bnf, abnf

I have the SDP grammar expressed in ABNF (i.e. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8866#name-sdp-grammar). I need an SDP parser. I immediately thought of bison but I doubt it supports ABNF grammars (I hope you will disprove me).
So I need to convert (manually or automatically) the ABNF grammar to a BNF that bison can handle.
What are the rules for such a conversion? I believe (and hope) that an ABNF grammar can also have a BNF representation.

PS: I remember some time ago I found a "conversion table" (which I can no longer find), and I remember that unfortunately some constructs peculiar to ABNF do not have a BNF counterpart. I hope I am wrong.